# Question concerning sum of diversities of all partitions of a natural number

Tags: combinatorics, elementary-number-theory

I am having trouble understanding the solution of a math problem that I've been working on in a book on elementary mathematics.

The problem goes :

"Given $n \in \mathbb{N}$, we define the diversity of a partition of $n$ as the number of distinct summands in it. Also, let $p(n)$ stand for the number of distinct partitions of $n$ and $q(n)$ for the sum of the diversities of all of the $p(n)$ partitions of $n$. Prove that :
\begin{equation}
q(n) = 1 + p(1) + p(2) + \dots + p(n-1)
\end{equation}
"

In the answer key they state that for any integer $1 \leq k \leq n-1$ there is a bijection between the partitions of $n$ having $k$ as one of its summands and the partitions of
$n-k$. I can see why this is true.

After they state this they say that the above fact means the contribution of $k$
to $q(n)$ equals $p(n-k)$. This apparently implies the correctness of the equation above that the reader is supposed to be proving. This second part is what I don't understand.

Can some one help me understand this second statement ?

Answer (score 1):

Let $\mathscr{P}(n)$ be the set of partitions of $n$, so that $|\mathscr{P}(n)|=p(n)$. For each $P\in\mathscr{P}(n)$ let $q(P)$ be the number of distinct summands of $P$, so that by definition

$$q(n)=\sum_{P\in\mathscr{P}(n)}q(P)\,.$$

Let $X=\{\langle k,P\rangle\in[n]\times\mathscr{P}(n):k\text{ is a summand of }P\}$; it’s a matter of calculating $|X|$ in two different ways. On the one hand

$$|X|=\sum_{P\in\mathscr{P}(n)}q(P)=\sum_{P\in\mathscr{P}(n)}\sum_{k=1}^n[k\text{ is a summand of }P]\,,$$

where the square brackets are [Iverson brackets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iverson_bracket). On the other hand, this is clearly

$$\sum_{k=1}^n\sum_{P\in\mathscr{P}(n)}[k\text{ is a summand of }P]=\sum_{k=1}^np(n-k)\,,$$

since $\sum_{P\in\mathscr{P}(n)}[k\text{ is a summand of }P]$ is the number of partitions of $n$ having $k$ as a summand, i.e., the contribution of $k$ to $q(n)$.